# Writing to a text file past a particular string

Tags: java, file-io

I'm looking for a way to write to a text file by searching for a particular string and writing past it. What I mean by this is I want to separate a text file into 2 sections, so that i can write to each section with separate java programs. My reason for this is that I'm running tests with 2 different java programs and storing the results in 2 text files at the moment, but i would like to have them both write to the same place, in different sections. Here is the code I am currently using to write with but i understand that this may all need to change in order to do what i want to do.

```
try {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    String content = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()) + " Test took: " + Test3 + " seconds.";

    File file = new File("mypath\\Test.txt");

    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
    }

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("mypath\\Test.txt",true);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    fw.write("\r\n");
    bw.write(content);
    fw.write("\r\n");
    bw.close();

    System.out.println("Done");

} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It currently stores the results of each test, separated by 1 line. What I'm hoping to do is put 2 sections into the same text file, and be able to add to the end of each independently. Is this even possible? And if so how would i go about doing that?

Comment: Sounds like an xy problem. What is actually being written to disk?

Answer (score -1):

As long as 2 Java programs are not writing to a file **at the same time**, this is one way you can have 2 programs write to different parts of the file.

Each program would create an instance of this class, and call the appropriate methods for the program (either the 1st program or the 2nd program).

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TwoPartFile {

    private String partOneHeader;

    private List<String> partOne;

    private String partTwoHeader;

    private List<String> partTwo;

    public TwoPartFile(String partOneHeader, String partTwoHeader) {
        this.partOneHeader = partOneHeader;
        this.partOne = new ArrayList<>();
        this.partTwoHeader = partTwoHeader;
        this.partTwo = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public TwoPartFile(File file, String partOneHeader, String partTwoHeader) {
        readFile(file, partOneHeader, partTwoHeader);
    }

    public void readFile(File file, String partOneHeader, String partTwoHeader) {
        // TODO Write code to read file and separate the components.
    }

    public void writeFile(File file) {
        // TODO Write code to write file from the components
    }

    public List<String> getPartOne() {
        return partOne;
    }

    public void setPartOne(List<String> partOne) {
        this.partOne = partOne;
    }

    public List<String> getPartTwo() {
        return partTwo;
    }

    public void setPartTwo(List<String> partTwo) {
        this.partTwo = partTwo;
    }

    public String getPartOneHeader() {
        return partOneHeader;
    }

    public String getPartTwoHeader() {
        return partTwoHeader;
    }

}
```